# Is there any 3D visualization library or toolkit for C? (No C++ please!)

Tags: c, opengl, scientific-computing

Basically I'm interested in knowing if there exists any openGL 3D visualization toolkit for C for scientific uses?

Comment: For what platform?  Linux, Windows, Mobile?

Comment: Linux, BSD, or any *nix. Free, opensource preferred.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about any straight forward libraries, but [Vis5D+](http://vis5d.sourceforge.net/) ist written in C, iirc. Maybe you can incorporate that into your project.

**Edit:** Oh, and of course [IBM's DX](http://www.research.ibm.com/dx/) is also there, but also not a library.

Comment: Just want to point out, in case anyone ever tries this again, that the IMB DX link above does nothing, and the last release of Vis5D+ was in 2001.

Answer (score -1):

Well, currently I'm using Matlab in combination with C by using the MEX interface. It allows me to write performant code in C (where Matlab code only is often too slow for real scientific computing) and visualize it with Matlab.

Check it out!